# Create multiple localStorage entries automatically

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I want to create a login by using js. For this, I want to use localStorage. It's easy to store just one email, since you can give it a key. But what if I want to create multiple entries for email? I've thought about using a variable (let's call it x) which is 0 when there is nothing in localStorage. It could be set to +1 any time a new Email is added. My idea would then be to write:

```js
let x = 0;

function addMail{
 usrInput = document.getElementById("userEmail").value;
 x = x + 1;
 localStorage.setItem("email" + x, usrInput);
}
```

That's the register part. But I'm lost when It comes to logging in. How can I check if that email the user types into the text-input (id = "usrEmail") is identical to *any* entry in localStorage?

Comment: What is the reason for storing emails on localStorage? It's not a good practice to begin with. It's not good to store sensitive data on localStorage. What do you want to do with those emails stored, and when do you want to store them?

Comment: Why do you think that it's not good practice? I want to be good with JavaScript before using a server-sided programming language. Ofc you shouldn't store real data in localStorage. But I want to learn the basics of programming and thought it would be a good Idea. Is there any way to store data more sensitive while not using PHP or NodeJS? If not, what would be a better practice? Thanks for your comment.

Comment: If it's for learning, it's not a problem, just keep in mind to not store sensitive data on localStorage since you will be subject to XSS attacks (https://shahjerry33.medium.com/xss-the-localstorage-robbery-d5fbf353c6b0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing email as the value in the local storage, you can store a whole array of emails by serializing it as JSON.

Push new email:

```js
const emailsInStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.get('emails') || '[]');
emailsInStorage.push('new@email.com');
localStorage.set('emails', JSON.stringify(emailsInStorage));
```

Check if email exists in the list:

```js
const emailsInStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.get('emails') || '[]');
const exists = emailsInStorage.includes('new@email.com');
```

---

##### Edit #1

Instead of constructing an array and serializing it as JSON, you can go ahead with your idea of storing different emails under different keys (`email1`, `email2`, etc.). Still, you'll have to store also the number of email keys you have already stored.

I attached an example you can play around with, but the JSON approach is better.

```js
function getEmailsCount() {
  return Number(localStorage.getItem('emails.count'));
}

function getEmailByIndex(index) {
  return localStorage.getItem(`emails.${index}`);
}

function saveEmail(email) {
  const nextIndex = getEmailsCount() + 1;
  localStorage.setItem(`emails.${nextIndex}`, email);
  localStorage.setItem('emails.count', nextIndex);
}

function isEmailExists(email) {
  const emailsCount = getEmailsCount();
  for (let i = 0; i <= emailsCount; i++) {
    if (getEmailByIndex(i) === email) return true;
  }
  return false;
}

saveEmail('email1@gmail.com');
saveEmail('email2@gmail.com');
saveEmail('email4@gmail.com');
saveEmail('email5@gmail.com');

console.log(isEmailExists('email1@gmail.com')); // true
console.log(isEmailExists('email2@gmail.com')); // true
console.log(isEmailExists('email3@gmail.com')); // false
console.log(isEmailExists('email4@gmail.com')); // true
console.log(isEmailExists('email5@gmail.com')); // true
console.log(isEmailExists('email6@gmail.com')); // false
```

Comment: tho I'm thankful for your proposal, I've never worked with JSON. Is there a way to do it without the use of JSON? or is my plan just too difficult for my ability? If that's the case, I'll wait a few hours for other ideas and then mark your proposal as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer to include a way to implement it without using JSONs. I don't recommend it, but I find it an excellent alternative to JSON.